# New class without passing constructor variables

Tags: php, symfony, oop

Probably a stupid question but what is the best way to do this?

So, I am using the two parameters in Emailservices' construct which are the entity manager and email factory.

The problem is that I want to call a function of this class from another, without adding these two parameters. It's needless to add these two in this case.

When i do $emailService = new EmailService(); i get the error too few arguments to function but if i pass the class EmailService $emailService as a parameter into SendPaymentEmail then it works - can you explain me why and what's the best approach here?

```
class EmailService
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
    private EmailFactory $emailFactory;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, EmailFactory $emailFactory)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $em;
        $this->emailFactory = $emailFactory;
    }
```

```
class PaymentService
{
    public function sendPaymentEmail(User $user)
    {
        $emailService = new EmailService();
        $sender = $this->container->get('twig')->getGlobals()['email_no_reply'];
    
        return $emailService->sendPaymentEmail($sender, $user, 'customer_home');
    }
}
```

Error: Too few arguments to function App\Service\EmailService::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/html2/app/src/Service/PaymentService.php on line 36 and exactly 2 expected

Comment: Things work when you inject EmailService because autowire is creating the service definition in the service container.  The request handler in turn uses the container to inject the service.  You could get rid of the error message with __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em = null, EmailFactory $emailFactory = null) but don't do that.  No reason not to use injection.  And while a bit off-topic perhaps, pulling information from the twig globals makes little sense.  You should probably define a service container parameter for that.

Comment: Please update your question to include how are you using `PaymentService::sendPaymentEmail($user)`. Effectively, Symfony services are intended to utilize Dependency Injection (DI) throughout your app. So anytime you call `new EmailService`, you are manually creating the service, as opposed to utilizing the Symfony DI from the container that has already been configured by the compiler. Autowire eases utilization of the DI by making it so you don't have to manually define the services in your configs.

Answer (score 1):

i cant understand your question is a little unclear but if you want to call a method of some class (without make an instance) from another class or function etc, you must to make the method static for example:

```
public static function sendPaymentEmail(User $user){...};
```

the call it like:

```
EmailService::sendPaymentEmail($user);
```

Comment: `sendPaymentEmail` is not a part of the `EmailService` class, it is part of the `PaymentService` class. OP improperly formatted the code, which made it look confusing.